# Python : What's wrong with my code of multi processes inserting to MySQL?

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I've write a Python script to insert some data(300 millions) to a MySQL table:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
import MySQLdb

from multiprocessing import Pool

class DB(object):

  def __init__(self):
    self.conn = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost',user='root',passwd='xxx',db='xdd',port=3306)
    self.cur = self.conn.cursor()

  def insert(self, arr):
    self.cur.execute('insert into RAW_DATA values(null,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)', arr)

  def close(self):
    self.conn.commit()
    self.cur.close()
    self.conn.close()


def Import(fname):
  db = DB()

  print 'importing ', fname
  with open('data/'+fname, 'r') as f:

    for line in f:
      arr = line.split()
      db.insert(arr)

  db.close()


if  __name__ == '__main__':
  # 800+ files
  files = [d for d in os.listdir('data') if d[-3:]=='txt']

  pool = Pool(processes = 10)
  pool.map(Import, files)
```

The problem is, the script runs very very slow, is there any obvious wrong using of multiprocessing ?

Comment: You should run a profiler to check that the database backend is taking all the time.

Comment: Why are you trying to parallelize an I/O-bound task?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, if you are bulk-inserting 300 million rows into the same table, then you shouldn't try to parallelize this insertion. All inserts must go through the same bottlenecks: updating the index, and writing into the physical file on the hard disk. These operations require exclusive access to the underlying resources (the index, or the disk head).

You are actually adding some useless overhead on the database which now has to handle several concurrent transactions. This consumes memory, forces context switching, makes the disk read head jump around all the time, and so on.

Insert everything in the same thread.

---

It looks like you are actually importing data from a kind of CSV file. You may want to use the built-in [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-data.html) MySQL command, designed for this very purpose. Please describe your source file if you need some help in tuning this command.

Comment: Thanks ! In fact, I've simplified the code, I need to do some text processing work before inserting. Can I use partitioning to speed this up ?

Comment: Partitioning *may* help if your partitions were located on different physical disks. It is very likely that your hard disk is the limiting factor. Besides, if the source file is located on the same disk as the database file, some I/O time is consumed just for reading it. Please monitor your system and confirm whether the CPU or the HDD is the bottleneck. A simple `top` will do. If your CPU is under 100% usage, or if it spends most of its time in "IO wait", then the HDD is the limiting factor.

Comment: Please also let us know whether the table is InnoDB or MyISAM.