# Updating one table of MYSQL with multiple processes via pymysql

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, csv, pymysql

Actually, I am trying to update one table with multiple processes via `pymysql`, and each process reads a CSV file split from a huge one in order to promote the speed. But I get the `Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction exception` when I run the script. After searching the posts on this site, I found one post which mentioned that to set or build the [built-in LOAD_DATA_INFILE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17816477/python-whats-wrong-with-my-code-of-multi-processes-inserting-to-mysql/53953200#53953200), but no details on it. How can I do it with 'pymysql' to reach my aim?

---------------------------first edit----------------------------------------

Here's the job method:

```
`def importprogram(path, name):
    begin = time.time()
    print('begin to import program' + name + ' info.')
    # "c:\\sometest.csv"
    file = open(path, mode='rb')
    csvfile = csv.reader(codecs.iterdecode(file, 'utf-8'))

    connection = None
    try:
        connection = pymysql.connect(host='a host', user='someuser', password='somepsd', db='mydb',
                                 cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
        count = 1
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            sql = '''update sometable set Acolumn='{guid}' where someid='{pid}';'''
            next(csvfile, None)
            for line in csvfile:
                try:
                    count = count + 1
                    if ''.join(line).strip():
                        command = sql.format(guid=line[2], pid=line[1])
                        cursor.execute(command)
                    if count % 1000 == 0:
                        print('program' + name + ' cursor execute', count)
                except csv.Error:
                    print('program csv.Error:', count)
                    continue
                except IndexError:
                    print('program IndexError:', count)
                    continue
                except StopIteration:
                    break
    except Exception as e:
        print('program' + name, str(e))
    finally:
        connection.commit()
        connection.close()
        file.close()
    print('program' + name + ' info done.time cost:', time.time()-begin)`
```

And the multi-processing method:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
def multiproccess():
    pool = mp.Pool(3)
    results = []
    paths = ['C:\\testfile01.csv', 'C:\\testfile02.csv', 'C:\\testfile03.csv']
    name = 1
    for path in paths:
        results.append(pool.apply_async(importprogram, args=(path, str(name))))
        name = name + 1

    print(result.get() for result in results)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

And the main method:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    multiproccess()
```

I am new to Python. How can I make the code or the way itself goes wrong? Should I use only one single process to finish the data reading and importing?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you are exceeding the time allowed for a response to be fetched from the server, so the client is automatically timing out. 
In my experience, adjust the wait timeout to something like 6000 seconds, combine into one CSV and just leave the data to import. Also, I would recommend running the query direct from MySQL rather than Python.

The way I usually import CSV data from Python to MySQL is through the INSERT ... VALUES ... method, and I only do so when some kind of manipulation of the data is required (i.e. inserting different rows into different tables).

I like your approach and understand your thinking but in reality there is no need. The benefit to the INSERT ... VALUES ... method is that you won't run into any timeout issue.